# To prove that a curve $\gamma_0$ is homotopic to another curve $\gamma_1$ as closed curves

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let U be an open subset of C. I need to prove the following
[image: page1]

I am struggling with this, since I am new to topology and the idea of homotopy. I would appreciate some way to make headway.

I am adding here a definition of homotopy with fixed end points and closed curves,as requested by @paulFrost

[image: page2]

The concatenation($\gamma_1+\gamma_2$) of two curves is defined as follows:
[image: page3]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble with Hatcher 1.1.6 (conjugacy and free homotopy)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3894782/trouble-with-hatcher-1-1-6-conjugacy-and-free-homotopy)

Comment: I don think it does @PaulFrost

Comment: Can I get a proof or a sketch of a proof? I am lacking some background here  @PaulFrost

Comment: It is the same, but perhaps you cannot see it without explanation. Do you know the concept of fundamental group?

Comment: No I dont @PaulFrost

Comment: You should explain your concept of "curve". It seems the domain of a curve is *any* interval $[a,b]$. I guess homotopic curves are required to have the same domain. How do you define $-\gamma$ and $\gamma_2  + \gamma_1$? If you want to show tha $\gamma_0$ is homotopic to  $\gamma_2 +  \gamma_1 +  (-\gamma_2)$, both curves must have have the same domain.

Comment: I have added a definition of homotopy and the domain of the curves as requested by you @PaulFrost. The domain is $\gamma:[0,1]x[a,b] \to U$.I have also edited the question.

Comment: Now you should fill one more gap (see my previous comment): How is $\gamma_2 + \gamma_1$ defined? On which interval do the $\gamma_i$ live and on which interval  $\gamma_2 + \gamma_1$ (similarly $\gamma_2 + \gamma_1 + (-\gamma_2)$)?

Comment: @PaulFrost $\gamma_i$ lie on the same interval $\gamma:[0,1] X [a,b]$, We must understand $\gamma_2$ and $-\gamma_2$ as traversals around $\gamma$ in the anti-clockwise and clockwise direction.

Comment: No, I mean the precise definition of the **sum** of two paths. This should be contained in your textbook.  Please add this to your question.

Comment: Added @PaulFrost

Comment: This is what I expected. But then we have the problem that $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_2 + \gamma_1 + (-\gamma_2)$ **do not live on the same interval** and the definition of homotopy does not apply. Does you textbook say anything concerning this problem? It can be resolved, but it is important to clarify it.

Comment: They live on the same interval, @PaulFrost

Comment: No, they do not. $\gamma_0, \gamma_1$ live on $[a,b]$, $\gamma_2$ lives on $[c,d]$. Possibly  $[c,d] = [a,b ]$, but this is irrelevant. According to your definition $\gamma_2 + \gamma_1 + (-\gamma_2)$ lives on $[c,d + (b - a) + (d -c)]$.

Comment: This is what I have - "we may assume they are all defined on the same interval, the difference would be an order preserving re-parameterization."

Comment: Okay, then it clear. Please add this essential information to you question. I shall give an answer this weekend.

Comment: Is it possible to give an answer before the end of today? I will add this to the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a topological space (if you want, you can restrict to $X = U \subset \mathbb C$). By $\mathcal P(X)$ let us denote the set of all curves $\gamma : [a,b] \to X$ which are defined on any closed interval $[a,b]$. Let $\mathcal L(X) \subset \mathcal P(X)$ denote the subset of all closed curves. We say that a closed curve $\gamma : [a,b] \to X$ is *based at $\xi \in X$* if $\gamma(a) = \gamma(b) = \xi$.

On $\mathcal P(X)$ we have two equivalence relations:

1. Homotopic with fixed endpoints. Here the curves have to be defined on the same interval.
2. Equivalent with respect to order preserving reparameterization. Here the curves may be defined on different intervals.

On $\mathcal L(X)$ we have one more equivalence relation:

3. Homotopic as closed curves. Here the curves again have to be defined on the same interval.

Taking **both** 1. and 2. generates a more general equivalence relation on $\mathcal P(X)$. More precisely, given curves $\gamma_i : [a_i,b_i] \to X$, $i = 0,1$, we write   $\gamma_0 \equiv \gamma_1$ if there exists an order preserving reparameterization $u : [a_0,b_0] \to [a_1,b_1]$ such that $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1 \circ u$ are homotopic with fixed endpoints. It is easy to verify that this is in fact an equivalence relation. Moreover, the choice of $u$ is irrelevant, i.e. we may take *any* reparameterization $u$ to check whether $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1 \circ u$ are homotopic with fixed endpoints. In fact, if $u ,v  : [a_0,b_0] \to [a_1,b_1]$ are order preserving reparameterizations, then they are homotopic keeping the endpoints fixed (a homotopy is given by $H(s,t) = su(t) + (1-s)v(t)$; note that for $s \in (0,1)$ both $su$ and $(1-s)v$ are strictly increasing, thus also their sum is). This means that $\gamma_1 \circ u$ and $\gamma_1 \circ v$ are homotopic with fixed endpoints.

**What you want to prove is this:**

> Let $\gamma_0, \gamma_1 :[a,b] \to X$ be two closed curves based at $\xi$. Then $\gamma_0, \gamma_1$ are homotopic as closed curves if and only there exists a closed curve $\gamma_2$ based at $\xi$ such that $\gamma_0 \equiv \gamma_2 + \gamma_1 + (-\gamma_2)$.

(1) Let  $\gamma_0, \gamma_1$ be homotopic as closed curves. Thus there exists a map $\gamma : [0,1] \times [a,b] \to X$ such that $\gamma(0,t) = \gamma_0(t)$ and $\gamma(1,t) = \gamma_1(t)$ for all $t \in [a,b]$ and $\gamma(s,a) = \gamma(s,b)$  for all $s \in [0,1]$. Define $\gamma_2 : [0,1] \to X, \gamma_2(t) = \gamma(t,a)$. Then $\bar \gamma = \gamma_2 + \gamma_1 + (-\gamma_2)$ lives on $[0,2+b-a]$. Note that
$$\bar \gamma(t) = \begin{cases}  \gamma_2(t) & 0 \leq t \leq 1 \\ \gamma_1(t - 1 +a ) & 1 \leq t \leq 1 + b - a \\ -\gamma_2(t - (2 + b -a))) = \gamma_2(2 + b -a - t) &  1 + b - a \leq t \leq 2 + b - a \end{cases}$$
Reparameterizing $\bar \gamma$ via $u : [a,b] \to [0,2+b-a], u(t) = p(t-a)$ with $p = \frac{2+b-a}{b-a}$, gives us a curve $\gamma^* = \bar \gamma \circ u$ and now it suffices to show that $\gamma_0, \gamma^*$ are homotopic with fixed endpoints. Note that
$$\gamma^*(t) = \begin{cases} \gamma_2(p(t-a)) & a \leq t \leq a + \frac{1}{p} \\ \gamma_1(a + \frac{b - a}{b - a - \frac{2}{p}}(t - a - \frac{1}{p})) & a + \frac{1}{p} \leq t \leq b - \frac{1}{p} \\ \gamma_2(p(b-t)) &  b - \frac{1}{p} \leq t \leq b \end{cases}$$
Define
$$\delta : [0,1] \times [a,b] \to X, \delta(s,t) = \begin{cases} \gamma_2(p(t-a)) & a \leq t \leq a + \frac{s}{p} \\ \gamma(s,a + \frac{b - a}{b - a - \frac{2s}{p}}(t - a - \frac{s}{p})) & a + \frac{s}{p} \leq t \leq b - \frac{s}{p} \\ \gamma_2(p(b-t)) &  b - \frac{s}{p} \leq t \leq b \end{cases}$$
This is a homotopy with with fixed endpoints such that $\delta(0,t) = \gamma_0(t)$ and $\delta(1,t) = \gamma^*(t)$.

(2) Let $\gamma_2 : [c,d] \to X$ be a closed curve based at $\xi$ such that $\gamma_0 \equiv \bar \gamma = \gamma_2 + \gamma_1 + (-\gamma_2)$. The latter lives on $[c,  2d - c + b-a]$. Reparameterize $\bar \gamma$ via $u : [a,b] \to [c,2d -c + b - a], u(t) = c + q(t-a)$ with $q = \frac{2d+b-a}{b-a}$ to obtain $\gamma^* : [a,b] \to X$. We know that $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma^*$ are homotopic with fixed endpoints. Thus there exists a map $\gamma : [0,1] \times [a,b] \to X$ such that $\gamma(0,t) = \gamma_0(t)$ and $\gamma(1,t) = \gamma^*(t)$ for all $t \in [a,b]$ and $\gamma(s,a) = \gamma(s,b) = \xi$  for all $s \in [0,1]$. Let $\partial R = [0,1] \times \{a,b\} \cup  \{0,1\} \times [a,b]$ be the boundary of $R = [0,1] \times[a,b]$. Consider the points $A = (0,a), B = (0,b), A' = (1/2,a), B' = (1/2,b), A'' = (1,a), B'' = (1,b)$ and $C = (1,u^{-1}(d)), D = (1,u^{-1}(d + b - a))$ on $\partial R$. There is a homeomorphism $h : \partial R \to \partial R$ which is the identity on the oriented line segment $\overline{AB}$ from $A$ to $B$ and maps *linearly* $\overline{AA'}$ to $\overline{AA''}$, $\overline{A'A''}$ to $\overline{A''C}$, $\overline{A''B''}$ to $\overline{CD}$, $\overline{B''B'}$ to $\overline{D'B''}$ and $\overline{B'B}$ to $\overline{B''B}$. Drawing a picture is helpful. There is an extension of $h$ to a homeomorphism $H : R \to R$. Define
$$\delta = \gamma \circ H : R \to X .$$
It is then easy to check that $\delta$ is a homotopy of closed curves from $\gamma_0$ to $\gamma_1$.

Comment: Really appreciate your answer @PaulFrost