# Let $ \alpha_0,\alpha_1,\beta$ loops based at $ b \in X,$ such that $\beta^{-1}\alpha_0 \beta \sim _h \alpha_1$ then $\alpha_0 \sim_h \alpha_1$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Using the homotopy between $\beta^{-1}\alpha_0 \beta$ and $\alpha_1$ Then is straightforward to find a continuous family $t \to \gamma_t$ of loops deforming $\alpha_0$ to $\alpha_1$, but I can't find this continuos family

Comment: There is an error in the title of your question. Please replace `\lpha` with `\alpha` to fix.

Comment: Are you talking about free homotopies? Because the statement is false for based homotopies in general.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by loop  (a closed path based at $b$ or a map $l: S^1 \to X$ such that $l(*) = b$?). What is the meaning of $\sim_h$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [To prove that a curve $\gamma_0$ is homotopic to another curve $\gamma_1$ as closed curves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3894752/to-prove-that-a-curve-gamma-0-is-homotopic-to-another-curve-gamma-1-as-clo)